# Read a csv file and separate lines into key and value to put in a hash table

Tags: java, csv, hash, hashtable, user-input

So a little info about my program, I implemented a hash table with separate chaining to handle collisions.

```
class TableInput{

     Object key;
     Object value;
     TableInput(Object key, Object value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
abstract class HashTable {
    protected TableInput[] tableInput;
    protected int size;
    HashTable (int size) {
        this.size = size;
        tableInput = new TableInput[size];
        for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++){
            tableInput[i] = null;
        }
    }
    abstract int hash(Object key);
    public abstract void insert(Object key, Object value);
    public abstract Object retrieve(Object key);
}
class ChainedTableInput extends TableInput {
    ChainedTableInput(Object key, Object value){
        super(key, value);
        this.next = null;
    }
     ChainedTableInput next;
}
 class ChainedHashTable extends HashTable {

    ChainedHashTable(int size) {
        super(size);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int hash(Object key){
        return key.hashCode() % size;

    }
    public Object retrieve(Object key){
        ChainedTableInput p;
        p = (ChainedTableInput) tableInput[hash(key)];
        while(p != null && !p.key.equals(key)){
            p = p.next;
        }
        if (p != null){
            return p.value;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void insert(Object key, Object value){
        ChainedTableInput entry = new ChainedTableInput(key, value);
        int k = hash(key);
        ChainedTableInput p = (ChainedTableInput) tableInput[k];
        if (p == null){
            tableInput[k] = entry;
            return;
        }
        while(!p.key.equals(key) && p.next != null){
            p = p.next;
        }
        if (!p.key.equals(key)){
            p.next = entry;
        }
    }
    public double distance(Object key1, Object key2){
        final int R = 6373;
        Double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(Object);

    }
    }
```

Now I have a csv file that contains city names, latitude and longitude.  I need to read the csv file from the command line argument and input the city names as the keys in the hash table and latitude and longitude as the value. My question is how can I read the csv file and separate the data into key and value objects to be put in the hash table?

Comment: Depending on the how you format your CSV file, I would recommend you to put key as the first column. You can put it in any column but you need to follow the same rule.

Comment: do you think you can elaborate please? I'm confused

Comment: Set each row for each city, say city name, lat, longi etc., what you need to do is to read those 3 fields for each time, before assembling them into a City object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this -

```
String csvFilePath = args[0];
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";

HashTable chainedHashTable = new ChainedHashTable(100);

try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] cityRow = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            String cityName = cityRow[0];
            Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(cityRow[1]);
            Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(cityRow[2]);
            Coordinate coordinate = new Cordinate(latitude, longitude);

            chainedHashTable.insert(cityName, coordinate);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


class Coordinate {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    Coordinate (double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    // Other setters and getters
}
```

Comment: This makes so more sense.  But I keep getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundException error with some big number

Comment: How do I know what size to set it to? Because the CSV file contains about 10000 items.

Comment: in that case initialize size of chainedhashtable with a value more than your expected number of records. `HashTable chainedHashTable = new ChainedHashTable(20000)`.
Ideally it show grow internally whenever it reaches certain % of current set size, like arraylists.

Comment: I fixed that. But the _while_ loop doesn't seem to read the file properly because when I _System.out.print_ a key, it gives me this: className.Coordinate@6016a786

Comment: Is there a way I could use (System.in) and command-line arguments?

Comment: you need to override toString method for Coordinate, to be able properly system out the object. otherwise u will have to use getters.

Comment: It kind of works but it gives me the wrong latitude and longitude.  I think it's giving two latitudes.